# ggplot show shares in brackets next to counts in geom bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

Let´s assume I have a simple data frame with categories, counts and shares, which I want to plot using `ggplot`

```
cat1 <- c("category1",
          "category2",
          "category3",
          "category4",
          "category5")
count <- c(12, 43, 31, 25, 11)

df <- data.frame(cat1, count)
df$share <- df$count / sum(df$count) * 100

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(cat1, count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(count, 2)), vjust = "bottom", size = 5)
```

Is there a way to show the shares in brackets next to the counts as labels on top of each bar, like it is made in the screenshot below (taken from [this blog](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/miscellaneous-show-counts-and-percentages-for-bar-plots.html)) ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `paste0` to add a column of labels to your dataframe. To achieve your desired result you could use `paste0(round(df$count, 2), " (", round(df$share, 1), "%)")`:

```r
cat1 <- c("category1",
          "category2",
          "category3",
          "category4",
          "category5")
count <- c(12, 43, 31, 25, 11)

df <- data.frame(cat1, count)
df$share <- df$count / sum(df$count) * 100
df$label <- paste0(round(df$count, 2), " (", round(df$share, 1), "%)")
require(ggplot2)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggplot2

ggplot(df, aes(cat1, count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), vjust = "bottom", size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: awesome, thanks! 
I have tried it on my original data now. The labels are quite long now. Is there also a way to use two lines for the labels?

Comment: You can add a manual line break with "\n" like so `df$label <- paste0(round(df$count, 2), "\n(", round(df$share, 1), "%)")`

Answer (score 1):

You can add text manually

```
ggplot(df, aes(cat1, count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = 14, label = "[square]",hjust=0.5, vjust=0, 
           cex=5, fontface=2, col="black")
```

[image]